# Use other columns with .SD in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to combine .SD with some other columns in a summarize operation, but this results in incorrect results (for my objective). For (a silly) example:

```
library(data.table)

t <- as.data.table(mtcars)

t[, list(cyl = sum(cyl), lapply(.SD, mean)), .SDcols = c('mpg', 'disp')]
```

I'd like this to return a data.table with 1 row and 3 columns, but instead it returns a column with 2 rows and 2 columns. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Please take your time to study documentation and the great collection of examples in `?data.table` and `.SD`. There you would have found: `DT[, c(.N, lapply(.SD, sum)), by=x]`; `DT[, c(.(y=max(y)), lapply(.SD, min)), by=rleid(v), .SDcols=v:b]`. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `list(cyl, lapply(.))` is returning something that is not really frame-like. If you look at that outside of the `data.table` environment, that looks like:

```r
str(list(cyl = sum(t$cyl), lapply(t[,c("mpg","disp")], mean)))
# List of 2
#  $ cyl: num 198
#  $    :List of 2
#   ..$ mpg : num 20.1
#   ..$ disp: num 231
```

when a better return would look something like:

```r
str(c(list(cyl = sum(t$cyl)), lapply(t[,c("mpg","disp")], mean)))
# List of 3
#  $ cyl : num 198
#  $ mpg : num 20.1
#  $ disp: num 231
```

Instead, `c`oncatenate two lists:

```r
t[, c(list(cyl = sum(cyl)), lapply(.SD, mean)), .SDcols = c('mpg', 'disp')]
#      cyl      mpg     disp
#    <num>    <num>    <num>
# 1:   198 20.09062 230.7219
```

or just concatenate a numeric `sum(cyl)` to the `lapply` list (thanks BrianMontgomery):

```r
t[, c(cyl = sum(cyl), lapply(.SD, mean)), .SDcols = c('mpg', 'disp')]
```

Comment: Or just t[, c(cyl = sum(cyl), lapply(.SD, mean)), .SDcols = c('mpg', 'disp')]

Answer (score 1):

Using `append`

```
setnames(t[,  append(sum(cyl), lapply(.SD, mean)), .SDcols = c('mpg', 'disp')], 1, 'cyl')[]
   cyl      mpg     disp
1: 198 20.09062 230.7219
```